# Visual Basic COMException error

Tags: vb.net, excel

Hi I have some VBA code that searches for duplicate rows in excel based on specific columns to look at. I am attempting to convert it to VB however am getting the error:
*COMException was unhandled
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0005 (CTL_E_ILLEGALFUNCTIONCALL)*

I get this on the line "If includedColumns.Exists(j) Then".
Code is:

```
Public Sub btnRun_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook1 As Excel.Workbook ' Interactions
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks

    Dim MainSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
    xlWorkBook1 = xlWorkBooks.Open(File1_name)

    MainSheet1 = xlWorkBook1.Sheets(1)
    Dim InteractionRows As Long = MainSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Total number of rows in the Interaction worksheet
    Dim totalURCols As Long = MainSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' get last used col on sheet for duplicate issue calc

    ' For Duplicate Issue ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Const LAST_COL As Long = 40 ' Update last column + 1 (ie. will update the 41th column, AO)
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2 ' The row the data starts, ie not including the header
    Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1 ' The row the data starts
    Const dupe As String = "1" ' This will be the flag
    Const CASE_SENSITIVE As Byte = 1 ' Matches UPPER & lower

    Dim searchRng As Range ' Search Range
    Dim memArr As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim unique As String

    Dim includedColumns As New Scripting.Dictionary ' Define storage for the columns you want to be used as duplicate issue search criteria.Create a Dictionary (a storage method) from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library
    Dim valDict As New Scripting.Dictionary ' For Upper and Lower case comparison
    With includedColumns ' Add the following columns to the Dictionary
        .Add(4, "")  ' Creation date
        .Add(8, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 8 (H) CALL_TYPE as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(10, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 10 (J) IT_Service as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(11, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 11 (K) Business_Service as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(21, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 21 (U) Affected_Staff_Id as duplicate issue criteria
    End With
    unique = vbNullString
    If CASE_SENSITIVE = 1 Then
        valDict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        valDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    End If

    ' Flag Creation
    searchRng = MainSheet1.Range(MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, FIRST_COL), _
                            MainSheet1.Cells(InteractionRows, LAST_COL))
    If LAST_COL < totalURCols Then
     MainSheet1.Range(MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, LAST_COL + 1), _
           MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, totalURCols)).EntireColumn.Delete()   'delete any extra columns
    End If

    memArr = searchRng.Resize(InteractionRows, LAST_COL + 1)  'entire range with data to mem

    For i = 1 To InteractionRows                              'each row, without the header
    For j = 1 To LAST_COL                           'each col
    If includedColumns.Exists(j) Then
    unique = unique & searchRng(i, j)       'concatenate values on same row
    End If
    Next
    If valDict.Exists(unique) Then                  'check if entire row exists
     memArr(i, LAST_COL + 1) = dupe              'if it does, flag it in last col
    Else
    valDict.Add(Key:=unique, Item:=i)            'else add it to the dictionary
    memArr(i, LAST_COL + 1) = "0"
    End If
    unique = vbNullString
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not use System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object) instead of Scripting.Dictionary? It has methods ContainsKey and Contains which you can use to detect duplicates.

Comment: Sarvesh, could you please give me an example using my code, how I could use implement it?

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach using Generic Dictionary

```
Public Sub btnRun_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook1 As Excel.Workbook ' Interactions
    Dim xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks

    Dim MainSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
    xlWorkBook1 = xlWorkBooks.Open(File1_name)

    MainSheet1 = xlWorkBook1.Sheets(1)
    Dim InteractionRows As Long = MainSheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Total number of rows in the Interaction worksheet
    Dim totalURCols As Long = MainSheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count ' get last used col on sheet for duplicate issue calc

    ' For Duplicate Issue ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Const LAST_COL As Long = 40 ' Update last column + 1 (ie. will update the 41th column, AO)
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2 ' The row the data starts, ie not including the header
    Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1 ' The row the data starts
    Const dupe As String = "1" ' This will be the flag
    Const CASE_SENSITIVE As Byte = 1 ' Matches UPPER & lower

    Dim searchRng As Range ' Search Range
    Dim memArr As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim unique As String

    Dim includedColumns As New Dictionary(Of Long, Object) ' Define storage for the columns you want to be used as duplicate issue search criteria.Create a Dictionary (a storage method) from the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library
    Dim valDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Long) ' For Upper and Lower case comparison
    With includedColumns ' Add the following columns to the Dictionary
        .Add(4, "")  ' Creation date
        .Add(8, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 8 (H) CALL_TYPE as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(10, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 10 (J) IT_Service as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(11, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 11 (K) Business_Service as duplicate issue criteria
        .Add(21, "")  ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< col 21 (U) Affected_Staff_Id as duplicate issue criteria
    End With
    unique = vbNullString
    'If CASE_SENSITIVE = 1 Then
    '    valDict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    'Else
    '    valDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    'End If

    ' Flag Creation
    searchRng = MainSheet1.Range(MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, FIRST_COL), _
                            MainSheet1.Cells(InteractionRows, LAST_COL))
    If LAST_COL < totalURCols Then
        MainSheet1.Range(MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, LAST_COL + 1), _
              MainSheet1.Cells(FIRST_ROW, totalURCols)).EntireColumn.Delete()   'delete any extra columns
    End If

    memArr = searchRng.Resize(InteractionRows, LAST_COL + 1)  'entire range with data to mem

    For i = 1 To InteractionRows                              'each row, without the header
        For j = 1 To LAST_COL                           'each col
            If includedColumns.ContainsKey(j) Then
                unique = unique & searchRng(i, j)       'concatenate values on same row
            End If
        Next
        If valDict.ContainsKey(unique) Then                  'check if entire row exists
            memArr(i, LAST_COL + 1) = dupe              'if it does, flag it in last col
        Else
            valDict.Add(unique, i)            'else add it to the dictionary
            memArr(i, LAST_COL + 1) = "0"
        End If
        unique = vbNullString
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers Sarvesh. Will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, it now throws the following error: InvalidCastException was unhandled
Operator '&' is not defined for 'Nothing' and type 'Range'.      This happens on the line unique = unique & searchRng(i, j) 'concatenate values on same row.        I changed the '&' to '+' but I get the same error.